# How to convert a string with special characters to a json object in powershell

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

I'm trying to convert a json string retrieved from the aws cli to a json object using powershell.
However in some case the string contain a special character that it can't decode :

```
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2192' in position 681: character maps to <undefined>
```

The full error is :

```
ConvertFrom-Json: Scripted.ps1:18:19
Line |
  18 |      $res = $res | ConvertFrom-Json
     |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Conversion from JSON failed with error: Unexpected end when reading token. Path 'Findings[98]'.
```

The code that i'm using is :

```
$res = aws securityhub get-findings
$res = $res | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Is there any way to delete this character or to decode it correctly ?

Following @bcbabrich answer, i added :

```
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$res = aws securityhub get-findings
$decoded = $enc.GetBytes($res)
$encoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($decoded)
$encoded = $encoded | ConvertFrom-Json
$res = $encoded
```

But i still get the same error.

Regards,
Q.

Comment: Can you show the response from ```aws securityhub get-findings```, or a representative sample that throws the same error? (Or maybe I'm misreading and ```'charmap' codec can't encode character ...``` *is* the output from ```aws securityhub get-findings```?)

Comment: @mklement0 - I’ve re-read this question a few times now and I *think* the first error message is a python error - I get the feeling ```aws.exe``` (compiled python?) is choking on an invalid response from the underlying AWS API, and the OP’s code is trying to convert the part-json / part-error message data from stdout. That’s a bit of a stretch though, so hopefully the OP can confirm by running the aws command in isolation and adding the output…

Comment: Good points, @mclayton. Indeed it sounds like Python. If `aws.exe` is sensitive to the same environment variables as Python scripts are, then a combination of `$env:PYTHONIOENCODING='utf-8'` (or, in v3.7+, `$env:PYTHONUTF8=1`) and `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()` before the `aws` call may help.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to encode the output from `aws securityhub get-findings` using `UTF8`. Try this:

```
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$res = aws securityhub get-findings
$res = $enc.GetBytes($res)
$res = $res | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: From what i could tell from your code, $res get converted to a bytes array, so i modified my code (example above) to reconvert it back to a string (utf-8)

Comment: When PowerShell, up to at least v7.3.x, captures output from an external program, it invariably _decodes it into a .NET string_, based on the encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`. Therefore, any potential mis-decoding has already happened by the time `$res` is assigned to. More fundamentally, passing a _byte array_ - such as output by `.GetBytes()` - to `ConvertFrom-Json` will _not_ work as intended, because each byte's decimal representation will be treated as a _string_, which is not the intent; e.g. `[byte[]] (65, 66) | ConvertFrom-Json`